# Getting 'TypeError: 'int' object is not callable' when using a class in python

Tags: python, class, oop, pygame

I am using a class in python (I am also using pygame in this program) but it will not allow me to call this particular method. The class is called 'enemy'.
This is the problem method:

```
    def attack(self, screen):
    self.charx = self.screen.get_width()/2 - self.pic.get_width()/2
    self.chary = self.screen.get_height()/2 - self.pic.get_height()/2
    textbox(self.screen, self.charx - self.c.rect.x + self.rect.x, self.chary - self.c.rect.y + self.rect.y, 15, 5, True, (255, 255, 255), True, (0, 0, 0), 0, '', True, (255, 0, 0), 15*self.healthpercent)

    if self.rect.colliderect(self.w.rect):
        if self.agility*random.randint(1, 10) > self.c.agility*random.randint(1, 10):
            self.c.health -= self.level*5  
        if self.agility*random.randint(1, 10) <= self.c.agility*random.randint(1, 10):
            self.health -= self.w.weaponpower*self.c.strength
            self.healthpercent = self.health/self.level*100

    if self.health == 0:
        self.dead = True
```

This is how I am calling it:

```
    e = enemy(enemypics, 50, 50, 4, 3, screen, c, bgdict, w)
    if e.dead == False:
        e.attack(screen) #stops on this line 
        e.update(screen)
    else:
        e.die(screen, timesincelasttick)
```

Obviously some variable names etc are defined elsewhere, but I didn't think those bits were necessary.
This is the full stack trace:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "E:\Code\Game\Main6.py", line 119, in <module>
        e.attack(screen)
    TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
    >>>
```

Comment: If you are getting an error, **post the full stack trace**

Comment: Your indentation is incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probable cause of this error is that somewhere else in your program you have a variable named `attack` and you have assigned an `int` value to it.

So when you do

```
e.attack(screen)
```

you are trying to call a function on that `int` variable `attack`

Make sure you don't have a variable named `attack` somewhere else in your program

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it! I was accidentally reusing 'attack', changing it and making it an int object. I have renamed the 'attack' variable and it now works.